# netbeans: How to compile a .jar file from a project with other project dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, compilation

I have a project which has other projects as dependencies (not just .jar files, actual projects). How do i make sure those projects are included in the final .jar file after building? Do i have to compile each project individually and put their .jar files in the lib folder?

Comment: Yes you have to build jars for all those dependent projects and then include them in your final jar. The JAR is agnostic to the build tool so if you think about it it makes sense for it to require dependencies as JARs rather than as projects otherwise it has to cater for all build tools out there and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code for doing that by

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec("javac className");
```

Comment: before you use those projects .

Comment: @FrankK Try it and if you find it as a solution plz make it as an accepted Answer

Comment: i'd love to, but i don't have a clue how i would have to implement this